# Javascript replace every line of value

Tags: javascript, replace

So I have this script which has to find some text on the first textarea (right away when text is pasted), then replace it with another one and give the result to another textarea.

The problem is that it's replacing the text only for the first line. And I want it to replace it on the All lines.

My code: (doesn't work on JSfiddle, but do on HTML)

```
<script>
function go()
{
var str = document.getElementById("a").value;
resa=str.replace("http://","www.");
resb=resa.replace(".com","");
document.getElementById("b").value=resb;
}
</script>

<textarea rows="10" cols="140" onkeyup="go()" id="a">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="10" cols="140" onkeyup="go()" onclick="this.focus();this.select();" id="b">
</textarea>
```

So if you try to enter https://google.com in every line you will get right text on the other textarea, but only in the first line.

Comment: **1.** This could work in fiddle if you change `onLoad` option to one of the `nowrap` options. **2.** To make this work even on copy/paste operations `onkeyup` might not be enough for all cases. **3.** This is just a guess but I imagine second textarea's value is gonna be used somewhere else later so actually there 's no need for replace operations on keyup in the first place. Just do it when the whole writing is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a global replace.

```
var str = document.getElementById("a").value;
var resa=str.replace(/http\:\/\//g,"www.");
var resb=resa.replace(/\.com/g,"");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have problem changing http:// on this code. I want to use http://long.domain.com/ws/ws/ (with the slash) instead of http://, but it keeps showing error

Comment: You need to escape slashes when using a regex.

Comment: I found out I had to escape a question mark with \\ witch was on my link. Now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that only the first line is replaced. The problem is you're only replacing the first occurrence.

Change to use a regex to replace all:

```
var resa = str.replace(new RegExp('http://', 'g'), 'www.');
var resb = resa.replace(new RegExp('.com', 'g'), '');
document.getElementById("b").value = resb;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. however resa does the trick, but the resb doesn't. tried to change strings, but nothing.